# findEdges() returning empty Set after working the first time?

Tags: c++, oop, graph

I am creating a graph class that implements a findEdges() function. I created the graph class using an adjacency list using the std::list<>. For some reason when I run my driver program it reads from a file and creates the graph correctly. But when I try to choose a point and use findEdges() it works for the first test case but any case I read in after that just returns a blank set for some reason.

I will post some code below:

```
class Graph
{
  public:
   // Non-Default Constructor                                                                                                                            
   inline Graph(int num) : cap(num), numItems(0) { adjList = new list<Vertex[num]; }

   // Copy constructor                                                                                                                                   
   inline Graph(const Graph & rhs) throw (const char *)    { *this = rhs; }

  // Destructor                                                                                                                                         
  inline ~Graph() {delete [] adjList;};

  // Assignment operator                                                                                                                                
  inline const Graph & operator = (const Graph & rhs) throw (const char *);

  inline bool isEdge(const Vertex v1, const Vertex v2) const;
  inline Set<Vertex> findEdges(CourseVertex theVertex);

  inline void add(Vertex v1, Vertex v2);
  inline void add(Vertex v1, Set<Vertex> groupV);

  inline int size() const { return cap; }

  inline void clear() {numItems=0;}

 private:                                                                                                                                             
  list<Vertex> * adjList;
  int cap;
  int numItems;
};
```

**Find Edges Function:**

```
Set<Vertex> Graph::findEdges(CourseVertex theVertex)
{
  Set<Vertex> edges;

  // Loop through adjList array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  for(int i = 0; i < cap; i++)
  {
     // Find v1's adjacency list                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     if (*adjList[i].begin() == theVertex)
     {
        //cerr << adjList[i].getText() << endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        // Loop through adjacency list and find vertices                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        // containg and edge with theVertex                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        for(list<Vertex>::const_iterator it = adjList[i].begin();
           it != adjList[i].end(); ++it)
           {
              ++it;
              edges.insert(*it);
           }
     }

     // if have not found v2, return false (or if v1 is not in the list)                                                                                                                                                                                            
     return edges;
  }
}
```

**Driver Function:***

```
void testFindAll()
{

  try
  {
     Graph g1(28);
     CourseVertex vFrom;
     CourseVertex vTo;

     {
        Graph g2(g1.size());

        // read the class dependencies from a file                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        // CS124 CS165 CIT225 ECEN160 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        ifstream fin("/home/cs235/week13/cs.txt");
        assert(fin.good());
        while (fin >> vFrom)  // read the first vertex, the class                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        {
           cerr << "First Vertex:  " << vFrom.getText() << endl;
           while (fin >> vTo){ // keep reading until the "|" is encountered                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
              cerr << "Prerequisites: " << vTo.getText() << endl;
             g2.add(vFrom, vTo);
        }
           fin.clear();       // clear the error state which came from the "|"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
           fin.ignore();
        }
        fin.close();
        g1 = g2;

        //TESTING CORRECT INPUT GRAPHS - DELETE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
     /**********************************************************************/
        for (int i = 0; i < g2.size(); i++){
           list<Vertex>::const_iterator it;
           for( it = g2.adjList[i].begin(); it != g2.adjList[i].end(); ++it)
              cout << *it << " ";
           cout << endl;
     }

        for (int i = 0; i < g1.size(); i++){
           list<Vertex>::const_iterator it;
           for( it = g1.adjList[i].begin(); it != g1.adjList[i].end(); ++it)
              cout << *it << " ";
           cout << endl;
     }
     /**********************************************************************/
        g2.clear();
     }
     // g2 is destroyed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     // prompt for the next class                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
     cout << "For the given class, the prerequisites will be listed:\n";
     cout << "> ";
     while (cin >> vFrom)
     {
        Set <Vertex> s = g1.findEdges(vFrom);
        cerr << s << endl;
        for (SetConstIterator <Vertex> it = s.cbegin(); it != s.cend(); ++it)
        {
           cout << '\t' << (vTo = *it) << endl;
        }

        cout << "> ";
     }
  }
  catch (const char * error)
  {
     cout << error << endl;
  }
}
```

This is my output. The output that's between the curly brackets are how many Point there are until an edge.

So the file I read in should look like this:

```
CS165 CS124 |
CS235 CS165 |
CS237 CS165 |
CS238 CS237 |
CS246 CS235 |
CS306 CS235 CS237 |
```

This is what my output looks like:

```
For the given class, the prerequisites will be listed:
> CS165
    { CS124 }
        CS124
> CS235
    { }
```

This is what my output should look like:

```
For the given class, the prerequisites will be listed:
> CS165
    { CS124 }
        CS124
> CS235
    { CS165 }
        CS165
```

Due to some cerr's I'm able to see that it's creating my graph correctly, with the right edges and everything. For some reason my findEdges() function returns an empty set when I attempt to find the edge of anything past the first line of the graph. Any help is appreciated.

**Assignment Operator:**

```
const Graph & Graph::operator = (const Graph & rhs) throw (const char *)
{
  if (this != &rhs) // check that not self-assignment                                                                                                                               
  {
     //--Allocate a new array if necessary                                                                                                                                          
     if (cap != rhs.cap)
     {
        //delete [] adjList;                                                                                                                                                        
        cap = rhs.cap;
        adjList = new std::list<Vertex>[cap];

        if (adjList == 0)  // Check if memory available                                                                                                                             
        {
           std::cerr << "ERROR: Unable to allocate a new buffer for Vector\n";
        }
     }
     //--- Copy rightHandSide's list elements into this new array                                                                                                                   
     cap = rhs.cap;
     for (int i = 0; i < cap; i++)
     {
     //std::cerr<<adjList[i]<<std::endl;                                                                                                                                         
     adjList[i] = rhs.adjList[i];
     }
  }
  return *this;
}
```

Comment: *Due to some cerr's I'm able to see that it's creating my graph correctly,* -- Learn to use the debugger.  It is much more helpful than using `cerr`.

Comment: `for(list<Vertex>::const_iterator it = adjList[i].begin(); it != adjList[i].end(); ++it)  { ++it;` -- Why are you incrementing `it` twice per loop iteration?  And this: `g1 = g2;`  We need to see your assignment operator.  If it's anything like your copy constructor, it is wrong.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I increment it twice because if I don't it will output the entire set when I got to print in my driver function. So it will output CS124 and below it print CS165. I edited my post to have my assignment operator. **This is a group project, not all the code is mine**

Comment: By incrementing the iterator again, you are now dereferencing the `end()` iterator on the last loop iteration at this line `edges.insert(*it)`, which is undefined behavior.  Second, you should move that assignment operator code into the copy constructor and implement the assignment operator in terms of the copy constructor.  It is much easier that way, as you can do the `copy / swap` idiom inside the assignment op.  Second, your assignment op has several flaws, One a memory leak, and two, not exception safe.

Comment: `list<Vertex> * adjList;`  Could simply be `std::vector<std::list<Vertex>> adList;` and then you don't need any assignment operator or copy constructor (or destructor) for the `Graph` class.